# Can't filter right

Tags: jquery

I was trying to do a filter/search with `jquery`, but my search isn't giving me the result i want. First of all this code uses twig to show the items from the database.

My problem is that, it's searching only for the line of the table row like e.g. If I search for the title, only the title will appear and none of the other information nor the image.

I want my output to be like my [first print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRaBK.png)

---

*view*

```
<div class="expandedContent">
              <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
                {% for item in processador %}

                <div class="product-removal"  >

                    <article class="product">
                        <header>
                            <img src="{{ item.img|e }}">
                        </header>
                        <div class="content" >
                            <button name="proc" id="{{ item.id|e }}" type="button"
                                    class="close close-processador pull-right" aria-label="Close"
                                    data-id="{{ item.id|e }}" data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h1>{{ item.marca|e }}</h1>
                            {{ item.descr|e }}
                        </div>
                        <footer class="content">
                            <h2 class="full-price fixed fixed-processador">
                                {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                            </h2>
                            <a data-versao="{{item.versao|e}}" class="adicionar adicionar-processador pull-right full-price"
                               data-modelo="{{ item.modelo|e }}" data-id="{{ item.id|e }}"
                               data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
                                <h2 class="full-price">
                                    {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                                </h2>
                            </a>
                            <h2 class="price">
                                {{ item.preco_unit|e }}
                            </h2>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
                <button class="mostrar" data-estado="mostrar">mostrar</button>
    </div>
```

*jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".product-removal *").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });
```

---

- [First view of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRaBK.png)
- [searching a "i"-gives me the title the info but not the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ5r3.png)]
- [searching "o" - gives only the info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6sA0.png)

Comment: cant you do something simple like `$(".product-removal:contains("+value+")").show()` to show the elements that contains your search value?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: but you will not see anything because the info comes from the database

Comment: @RafaelCraveiro in your browser you can inspect the element, then find  `expandedContent` in your HTML and copy the entire HTML of that element. then you have the code we need to test your problem for you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h2aohoqh/1/

Comment: Create a fiddle with the generated output and not with your `twig` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the function [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) correctly . The function `filter` expect a `selector` or a function which returns a `boolean`. It will then reduce the result set by only returning the elements of which the function return `true`

If you want to use this function you would need to swap your code to something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('div.product-removal article.product').toggle(true); //Show all products again
      $('div.product-removal article.product').filter(function(index, elem) {
          return $(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1; //return true when the text is not found
      }).toggle(false); //filter will return all products which does not contain the search query
    });
});
```

---

But I'm feeling you would be more comfortable with the following aproach

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('div.product-removal article.product').each(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      });
    });
});
```

*Also note I used the html property of the parent container `article.product` instead of each element seperatly so this code will return some false positives now and then*